# GCM on Android TV

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-tv

Does an Android TV device can receive and display GCM Push Notifications? 
I couldn't find any information saying yes or no, so I assume that it can.

Does anyone knows if it's supported and if GCM is supported, are push notifications displayed while watching regular tv or just if the "home launcher" of android tv is visible on screen?

Comment: I would assume that too. Android is Android. I would create a simple test Android TV app to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GCM to push message to android TV and display the notification in "Recommendations Row" as Cards. 
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations.html

Answer (score 4):

`GCM` stands for `Google Cloud Messaging`, and it's a service that allows you to establish a communication channel with a device (typically, Android-based). It has nothing to do on the way you display the received data! **Since Android TV is Android-based, GCM will work just fine on it.**

For this reason, you can choose to display a `Notification` as well as do whatever you want with the data that you receive. But notifications are not as straightforward and immediate on Android TV as they are on Android, so my suggestion is to display data in another way.